# ListSerializer for json on rest_framework serializers

Tags: python, django

I want to return the json like this,

```
{"texts":[
    "string1
    "string2"
    "string3"
]}
```

One simple index `texts` has `list`

my Object is here

```
class Task(object):
    def __init__(self, texts, created=None):
        self.texts = texts
        self.created = created or datetime.now()
```

The problem is serializer, because `texts` is `list` so I need to use `ListSerializer`

So I made this, but after serialized texts field is empty.

```
class TextsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    serializers.CharField(max_length=200) # There's something wrong....??

class TaskSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    texts = TextSerializer(many=True)
    created = serializers.DateTimeField()
```

---

Thanks to Reply

My solution is here

delete class TextSerializer and then, change TaskSerializer like this

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    texts = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField(max_length=200))
    created = serializers.DateTimeField()
```

Comment: So, you decided you need to use a `ListSerializer`, but you haven't used `ListSerializer` in the code you've shown us? And on the line where you have identified "there's something wrong", you haven't given a name to the field you've declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`serializers.ListField`**--(DRF doc)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield)

```
class TextSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    text = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField(max_length=200))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change **serializers.Serializer** to **serializers.ListField**

```
class TextSerializer(serializers.ListField):
    serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't assign your field to any variable

```
class TextSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    text = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    # ^ here
```